# Change img src and text based on element

Tags: javascript, html

First of all let me show you an image for better understanding:

[image]

When I click on the quickview button a popup window shows up, I would like to make this dynamic meaning that if I click on an item the img should change depending of which item was clicked.

Then comes the second functionality, which basically should change the popup window item "heading" name, "price" and "text" (if possible) based on the item description. Here's an image of the popup window:

[image]

This second image illustrates that I clicked on the first item, but if I click on the second one (or any other), the name, price and description should change along with the image. I imagine the functionality to change the image is probably not so complicated, but when it comes to the second functionality, I simply have no idea of how to achieve this, I don't want to think I have to build a different popup window in my html structure for each element.

```
<main>
    <section class="products-container container">
      <nav class="categories">
        <span class="categories__link" id="accesories">Accesories</span>
        <span class="categories__link">Bottoms</span>
        <span class="categories__link">Dresses + Jumpsuits</span>
        <span class="categories__link">Outerwear</span>
        <span class="categories__link">Tops</span>
        <span class="categories__link">— Sale</span>
      </nav>
      <div class="products">
        <a href="#" class="shop-item">
          <img src="img/haori-jacket.jpg" alt="Haori Jacket" class="shop-item__img">
          <div class="quickview">
            <span class="quickview__icon">Quick View</span>
            <span class="quickview__info">Haori jacket<br><span class="quickview__info--price">$210.00</span></span>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="shop-item">
          <img src="img/swing-dress.jpg" alt="Swing Dress" class="shop-item__img">
          <div class="quickview">
            <span class="quickview__icon">Quick View</span>
            <span class="quickview__info">Swing dress<br><span class="quickview__info--price">$218.00</span></span>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="shop-item">
          <img src="img/linen-top.jpg" alt="Linen Top" class="shop-item__img">
          <div class="quickview">
            <span class="quickview__icon">Quick View</span>
            <span class="quickview__info">Linen top<br><span class="quickview__info--price">$125.00</span></span>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="shop-item">
          <img src="img/lounge-jumpsuit.jpg" alt="Lounge Jumpsuit" class="shop-item__img">
          <div class="quickview">
            <span class="quickview__icon">Quick View</span>
            <span class="quickview__info">Lounge Jumpsuit<br><span class="quickview__info--price">$298.00</span></span>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="shop-item">
          <img src="img/lounge-tunic.jpg" alt="Lounge Tunic" class="shop-item__img">
          <div class="quickview">
            <span class="quickview__icon">Quick View</span>
            <span class="quickview__info">Lounge Tunic<br><span class="quickview__info--price">$258.00</span></span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Popup Shop Item -->

    <div class="popup-item">
      <div class="wrapper-item">
        <img src="img/haori-jacket.jpg" alt="Haori jacket" class="wrapper-item__img">
        <div class="product-info">
          <h2 class="heading-secondary">Haori jacket</h2>
          <span class="product-info__price">$210.00</span>
          <p class="product-info__text">Sed ornare tellus non lectus blandit faucibus. Curabitur convallis nibh ut libero lobortis ullamcorper. Aliquam ornare risus in orci iaculis egestas. Vivamus varius ipsum eu leo ...</p>
          <div class="detail-group">
            <p class="detail-group__span">Size:</p>
            <select class="detail-group__size">
              <option value="">Select Size</option>
              <option value="0">0</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="detail-group">
            <p class="detail-group__span">Quantity:</p>
            <input class="detail-group__quantity" max="9999" min="1" value="1" type="number">
          </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn--form btn--form--shop">Add to cart</button>
            <a href="" class="btn-view">View Full Item</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <span class="popup__close-icon" id="closeIcon">&times;</span>
    </div>
  </main>
```

Javascript to open popup

```
// Open popup shop item
  $('.quickview__icon').click(function (){
    $('footer').css('display', 'none');
    $('.popup-item').css({'opacity': '1', 'visibility': 'visible'});

    // Change popup shop item img source

  });
```

Comment: Also here's the code pen for more insight, although is not 100% perfect https://codepen.io/CodingGilbert/pen/NzQmpL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery's `$().attr()` or `$().prop()` to get the attribute of an element, like the `id` of a `<span>` or the `src` of an `<img>`. You can store values inside hidden `span`s which you can then extract later using `document.getElementById("id").innerHTML`.

```js
var numOfImages = 3;
var currentImg = null;
$('.quickview__icon').click(function(e){
   $('#popup').show();
   var imgid = "#"+$(this).attr('id').replace(/\s/g,'') + "img";
   var imgsrc = $(imgid).prop('src');
   var imgnumid = $(this).attr('id').replace(/\s/g,'') +"num";
   var imgnum = parseInt(document.getElementById(imgnumid).innerHTML, 10);
   currentImg = imgnum;
   if(imgnum==1){
    $('#previous').hide();
   } else {
     $('#previous').show();
   }
   if(imgnum==numOfImages){
     $('#next').hide();
   } else {
      $('#next').show();
   }
   var price = document.getElementById($(this).attr('id').replace(/\s/g,'')+"price").innerHTML;
   document.getElementById("clothingprice").innerHTML = price;
   $('#popupimg').prop('src', imgsrc);
   document.getElementById("clothingname").innerHTML = $(this).attr('id');
});
$('#closepopup').click(function(e){
 $('#popup').hide();
});
$('#next').click(function(e){
  if(currentImg==3){
  document.getElementsByClassName("quickview__icon")[0].click();
  } else {
  document.getElementsByClassName("quickview__icon")[currentImg].click();
  }
});
$('#previous').click(function(e){
 if(currentImg==1){
  document.getElementsByClassName("quickview__icon")[2].click();
  } else {
  document.getElementsByClassName("quickview__icon")[currentImg-2].click();
  }
});
```

```css
.clothing{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.quickview__icon{
  color: #ff0000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.popup{
  width: 50%;
  height: 90%;
  position: fixed;
  right: 25%;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: grey;
  top: 5%;
  opacity: 75%;
}
.close{
  font-size: 2em;
  position: fixed;
  right: 26%;
}
.close:hover{
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clothing">
<img id="Haorijacketimg" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxISERUQEhIVFhUXFRYSGBYYFRcWGRUYGxgXGBcbGBgYHSggGBolHRUVITEiJSkrLi4uFx8zODMtNygtLisBCgoKDg0OFhAPFS0dFRkrKy0tKysrKystNy0tKy0rLS03Ky0rLSs3LSs4LSstKzc3NysrNysrLSs3LSstKysrK//AABEIAQ0AuwMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAcAAEAAgMBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAABQYDBAcBAgj/xABDEAABAwIDBQQHBQYEBwEAAAABAAIRAyEEEjEFBkFRYRMicYEHMkJSkaHBFGKx0fAjJHKCkrKiwuHxMzRDU2STsxX/xAAXAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQID/8QAHBEBAQEAAQUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAERAiExMkFC/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDuKIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgKIqb0YFrgw4zDBxkQa9Oba2zdCq36Td7Bhqf2ak79rUHeIN6bD+DnXA5CTyX5tfiC2s+eBcB4F0q4P1/hds4aq7JTxFF7oJysqscYGpgGYW8vyPsbaj6dRmIpPy1KYJaRzkfEcwdZX6T3D3rZtHDCqAG1WwyrT913Aj7jtQfEagpYLKiIoCIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAsVeu1glzgB1WjtDaoZ3WwXfIfmq5jaxcZeSSpqJfGbxtFqbZ6mw+Gv4KHr7XxDgSahFrBsCOsgStUvCxVatoUHJdpVXOrOe9znuLjJJkm/VSu4mxPtNWr+2fShw9VlN1iAdXtPVRW3GRXqCSIe6w6mfqtvcfarcPXdJdfKdJ5zx8F1uZ1VJekXAHCAYcVHVGuIeC4MDrN70loEiXaRwUTuHXrMxbeze5mZj8+VxGZoaSJj72X9FbW/wBtRuJqscJDQzQxJOYi0cIAHkno9pB2JqOGjKJb5ueyP7XLM6cSuq4XeWvTALyKg5OsfJw+oKm9m72YerAcTTdpD9P6hb4wqhXb3VGubCyjr4K9XLdl7yVsNZpzM/7biY/lOrfw6LoWx9r08SzPTN/aafWaeo+uiqpBERAREQEREBERAREQFA7y7W7PLSYYc7UjUD81LY3FCmwuPkOZXOtvYomsxxPtSf15qVKlMLUluYi/HxFisVQzdYsC6Q5vgfxaf7Wn+ZbBaAojTcQsdRwhfVUiblamKrNAsg5xvPH2mpfiP7QofDVgKlhJiykd7GE4p1tWtPDqoan3HiDM2W74tRMbaMFgtam0ed3f5lY/RtS/5h9rmk34ZyfxHwVY2g5ueYJMNHwACuPo8b+71HcTWI+DGc/FO3GFWeu6Ao+vfQLYqnMbL57EDUrDLQdRdrCw4LadWlX/AGbi17RmMQQQbBpB4GPl4KUxdZoYXTYalc7wGPq4mu+mwlofUJc8ahgsADwsPiVVfondvbDcVRFQRmHdeAZh3TodR4qVXHdh7YOCxTXCeyc1tN7R7osCBzb+Y4rr9KoHAOaQQQCCNCDcEKxX2iIgIiICIiAvHOgSV6oHb+0P+k0/xH6INHa2O7R0j1RYfmqxtWHa8LhSlZ6r21axvF44LLLa2XjgXagES2Tpcf6A/wAqkMZX9hvDXqVWd3n5WPMZnGpZupdAmBwHESVlq1cVJzNa2/PMfkg36jYklaFV8mwB8VuUqb478LHVyj2ZQc83zBGIuYljdIHNV+jAeI/FWLfhodiGkiO51PE8VXWMAqNha+WoksVUJcfFX7ckRgmnm+o7XWHFv+Vc7qQSZPFdH3SblwVHugmKjrnnVeR8iFeXZEsyk5yyjCtF3GV4HVXCwDBzWria7GiM+YrCIbfjHxhagYCYadBZvWTayr25Qhlhfipbel7DhKwbrkPkofc+pDAOvxKqrBj2u14K++jfb8j7HUNwJpE8Rq5nlqOk8lSsee6SfNaWy6721GuacrmkPB5HUKD9AIo/Ye024mg2sLSIcPdcLOHx+UKQWlEREBEXzUeGguJgASSg09rY4UmT7Rs0defgFUHvJJJuTeVm2ljjVqF3DRo5BaT6kLNqMWMqQFXcY+HZ+GhCldoVoBKrLdqNfPAaX5oiT2I0ioX8GmR/SdfIlbVG9QvLiSeHAKN3dx4qGqA4uFMAdA51xJ4mGnW91kpbTAeRbVBKVGPN5WCpTAubHqvmtXJNiVr4tznNiUFL36aHVmX9g+rbj89VW6NCKjSDN+KsG9bMtRg07p1GuighXAc3TVani1Gw53Jv4LqG7tVrMJQJEnsmwPG/1XK3PJOhXVNgtH2agTwoUgL/AHBoPqryRIVKua7haOa1H4ik32QsePxXABasB7YIA8TCwiub6Y15pPLcopxBAAm9hPHzsPFQ+5lbvgch81MbxbOaym452wRGQEuLzwETpPHgoDdZwpvl2rdfHQDxJVVfsbSzRJ7o7zuvIfrktWi8Q6oAYJidBHRbWWWAOGtz1TENloERGgCgse4W2uxr9k8xTrED+Gpo0+fq/wBPJdQlcNqC2XiPkup7mbc+1UBmP7WnDH9eTv5gPiCrFWBERUFWN5tpyexabD1up4Dy/WimNtY3saTnjXQdCeJXP3VzqbjUn8ZWbUrYc/qtR9S69rVNFrOfeyiNXaz5blB1UVupuqcfiHOc4jC0v+K6PWi/ZscDMketyB6hfe3qj3OZQpCalV7aTR95xgTyF5J4AFdSw+y2YDZv2dh9SnkLtC977Ocepc4laiqRtKpSYx2RrGAnPlFgxsZW91usNa0eSrOxml9TOQIkxIjzU1tytUf3KeYNGrgGkzxtMgLTwjHD1nEhouYykkiwgceOnAc1ESraoNszSeQKx132Oi+qbdBAniQBA6ayvqo2BcDxQUzauyTiKoGYNhpd/wAN5m4B7o/EWULtvYZo0zU7VhylvdALXGSBoT1V3w9Rv2iRPqHQX9ZvCLeMr43wc04KsJJ7oPwc0/RXVVMbvYgizG/+xn5q+bGZkoUmOjM2mxpFjcNANxM6eC+MEGdm2C020aGNn6rcae6ABrr/ALpbo8r0gbATP61Vb2lg5JDadMniXPcY8pCs9R4Y2bKA2hTD7EgA6uEZugkXE/rVQQR2IHGXVWiPZpNjykTdZdnbAzMONpmRSr9jWpmXFgIb2VQReDLmmeLRzMZn1TlNMnK1vdc1lNwnxIOh6/mpf0a4qmzGOwtQDssZTdh3NiBIDnMFtbdoJ5uCoyVHgAEnWwHE+S9zL3GYB2GrPovGao05Q4jVvsuHiIPRa+NqZbcVB8UqhMzp+K3929sHB4tlQnuO7lQfcPHxBg+XVRLAXPaNGi56ngF94/14sABcmwAQd9Y4EAgyCJkcV9KmejTbja2H+zknPSs2bF1L2SJ4D1fAN5q5rSvHNBEESFWNrbqi9TDnKdTT9k/w+6fl4K0Ig5NiqTmuLSC1wN2n8Y+q1DW1kQb/AKC6vtLZdKu2KjZ5OFnN8D9NFRdvbi4p8UqFamKbzle90tfTYT3i1oBDnRMXF1nExqei7ZBr1n7TqN7jc1LDzxOlSoPmwHq9XPfOtloBo9p4HlBP0Cl8BhGUabKNNoaxjWsa0aBoEAfJVjfyrekwffdx6AaeavoUTE0y9xmoTFgxjmj4n1o8wtr/APMLHFudrgwyS05ml5FzJgmPy5JPAazAhoED2nRfwWwdA1seJ/31UR8ds3Qa/BaGLqt9Vzi3wUkRAvB8AsL6sCzWjxIQQ2GIFYFo7vZugwb95nsgD4rQ3wc52EqnJDRl70gT3m+ypJri6uXFwnIReSPWFgbcuq1N93n7DUJIiaYgTxqNRUjsynFCnmIuxpghp4Dit+kSWiAONz4lQ+wsUHYamcrvUaCYLhMcxNlIMJyjKGk965MD1jxH5IhjQQC57gB5D8VWcZtBkk9owk2DWOZfxJYSPIrfx1emXft2NqEaBr3O/wAEQvuhi2OIFOk5n8NEE/E2CKjRRq2qB3C7gcpdOmQEXsPkea1qrqlNzMSHVHmk5lUOd2YbLHBwE2J0U3ii1pl1Ql3LK0OPQkXUHiAC4tIMXc0ZjA5iMwCDs++uyxiKLMZS9ZjQ4n3qRE/Fs5vDNzXLMW5xf3RJ58l170d4rtdm4cuvDTSPGzHFg+LQ34ql7c3afSxLmMovqhxzUw1pcIPA+yMuku6GRKtFZwWFcP2joMaX7oPMu4+UlYxh31aop02uq1XElrWjlqQDYAW7zjAtor3sz0fVaxz42qWN4UaThmj79SIHg3+pXnZWx6GGbloUmsFpIF3R7zjd3mUxVV3I3JdhnjFYioTWvDGu7jAQQcx1e6/gIETEq8oioIiICIiAqFvvW/eQOVIDjxMyYBjVX1c330qfvT+7mgNEW90HiRClSoyhQi4vwFxIHj+uCyZncY+qj6UatJaeRJ+SzHEHQEeB/NZRlqtIvqFo1qgJIcwHrAP0WV1U8RHmtWuBBLQSeQMFUY8JWaKj3RADW8AZBLuDT0UPv5jw/C5RN6jLRGhn6LfwZcH1O6fVp2gOOtT3I+pUPvyQaAloDs7Lw5p+BRYkN0toA4ZjNCGgWBP+gU41mZvq5rnV0ddYPNQW49IjCteXATPs9SNZup5tSxM8eWbgOaD2lRjSk0dZLvmQFo7TxbQC11Rw6MOX5tv81uPv7Z+ELXe4A3jzaD80EBTot1p0YPvOkn5OB+a8dg2sHbVnlo9kRlJ8G5iT8fFTGLxlSIptv70BQpoy/NUf2tTkLhv08gg6p6G8ZnwdRlxkrugEycrmtInrOZX5c09D1Tv4tnLsHfEVAdPBdKWor1F4iD1ERAREQEREBcz3u/5qr4s5e4Oa6YuZb4OBxdVsEepNtTkbcfEKVKhDSJ6FfGU+1froVkDeGoXgke1PisoxvEC7jHLiVqvpuPJg5NbmcfErLWMXLvktPtS4yGNMe082Hg0Kj2nTl1UEvEtp6CXa1ODZj5eShN9MAGYcO7V7u+2Gu8/NTmCf36kETDNO6D6/ifmorfVn7uCQJNRomSeaLEtug9v2KjOsO/vepXML3Ouv68FBbq4rLg6bcswXjh77j9VJtqWd7OlpLec3H0Qr7xL+c+a0nvAEzK+6gf7LmEcpJPzWhinxq0T0NkGDGVM1s0DjCwiuxgDGA35anz4LUx2JfoGj4fmvrZmDqOMk3Op/15eCDoXogqgYzEMgDNQY6B915GvE99dYXHPRc4N2s5maf3SoOk9pRMdLSuyKxRERUEREBERAREQFyDb21GVcRiKjTLRUNNp1nJ3HH+prh5K+ekHbbsHgK1dgJqZcjIBMOdYOdGjW3cSeS4xson7NSAeJyNd3gblzQ4mQeZPNZqVNYXGtfa4PVZXM4hQUVDduQu4FrtfHMBF5WtXxuMcDTy9mPeAzOPhBRE68tBlxCxOx9PgW+ZFlWquCqO7gbVDfacWvLneAiykMHhGUw2KL3O5mm8xxvZFb+EqF1SoZJGWncDN7/CdPBRW+rmigxrTJdUEuPQE+XBSeFzZqjyx18kd0h1g7gbjVRu8+z8Timsp0aFV7w7MWtYXOygEEmBpJF+oQjd3WaxuFaXQe87iVvduJdEeroDPHrYKJ2PgMRhKBp4ilUpEvc8CqwjMMrAYza3HzWN+KADnlrGDIY4TccNEG3jMWOUeX5LRlxvJhRhxL3AONdgHQtHlZfHbuMzVzAWtJk+SCQdBdClHVG02XcBaYVYZVrScjHTpJabfGy+zhKp7pgCxJe6S49csmOiCy+jfarae1KVUzlqF1EuP3wQD/AFZB4L9DL8xnAubSLzUBLRmGVuXLl74gzp3RwX6L3f2iMThaOIBkVKTH+ZAn5yrFSKIioIiICIiAiIg8Kisfu3g6xJq4ak4nV2QBx/mEH5qWRBT6vo3wEyxtSmQCBlqExPIVMy1h6NqI0xFY/wAQpu/BoV4RBz93o0/8sxrejMf418O9HFaZGOFtB9nMecVbroi8Uwxzl/o/xLZy16TiTqQ9nyGZSu527FfDV31a3ZmaZpgse9xu5p0c0QO6riiuCmekjY1fENonD0jUe0vBAcxsAhupcRxaqnh9z9pOIJoBliL1mXkfdcV19FMHKae420Dq3Dt8az5+DaZX2z0bYx3r16DOrRUfHkcs/FdTRMHM8N6JBY1sa95HuUm0/wC5z1L4T0Y4JnrOr1D96oB/82tV1RUQ2A3UwVGCzDU5GjnDtHDwc+SFMoiD1F4iD1ERAREQEREBERAReIg9ReIg9ReL1AREQEREBF4vUBEXiD1ERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQf/Z"width="50" height="50"/>
<br/>
<span class="quickview__icon" id="Haori jacket">
Quick View
</span>
<br/>
<span>
Haori jacket
</span>
<br/>
<span id="Haorijacketprice">
$210.00
</span>
<span id="Haorijacketnum" style="display: none;">1</span>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="clothing">
<img id="Linentopimg" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSHnKUQNqUcYm7fauoZSam3_c4gne4NemeUUyY2-RkvGWuOGR6O6g" width="50" height="50"/>
<br/>
<span class="quickview__icon" id="Linen top">Quick View</span>
<br/>
<span>Linen top</span>
<br/>
<span id="Linentopprice">
$170.00
</span>
<span id="Linentopnum" style="display: none;">2</span>
</div>
<div class="clothing">
<img id="T-shirtimg" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" width="50" height="50"/>
<br/>
<span class="quickview__icon" id="T-shirt">Quick View</span>
<br/>
<span>T-shirt</span>
<br/>
<span id="T-shirtprice">
$50.00
</span>
<span id="T-shirtnum" style="display: none;">3</span>
</div>
<div class="popup" style="display: none;" id="popup">
<span class="close" id="closepopup" title="Close">&times;</span>
<br/>
<img src="" id="popupimg" width="100" height= "100"/>
<br/>
<div style="width: 100%; position: relative">
<img id="previous" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/60/60965.svg" height="50" width="50" style="position: absolute; left: 3px;"/>
<img id="next" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/60/60758.svg" height="50" width="50" style="position: absolute; right: 3px;"/>
</div>
<div style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
<span id="clothingname"></span>
<br/>
<span id="clothingprice"></span>
</div>
<br/>
</div>
```

Comment: Somehow this isn't working for me? I get an error on the console:  Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined, this is the code `// Open popup shop item
  $('.quickview__icon').click(function (){
    $('footer').css('display', 'none');
    $('.popup-item').css({'opacity': '1', 'visibility': 'visible'});

    // Change popup shop item img, name, price
    var imgid = "#"+$(this).attr('id').replace(/\s/g,'') + "img";
    var imgsrc = $(imgid).prop('src');
    $('#popupImg').prop('src', imgsrc);
    document.getElementById("clotheName").innerHTML = $(this).attr('id');
  });`

Comment: @Gilbert From what I can see, you might have written the `id` of one of the attributes incorrectly. Would you consider putting the code in a JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) so I can see it?

Comment: Hey @hev1, I managed to fix the bug, it looks like I couldnt change the id name for the images. So far everything works as intended, except that I would also make the price and description of the popup dynamically. This piece of code is not working: `document.getElementById("itemPrice").innerHTML = $(this).attr('id');` When I do this instead I got the item's name and not the price.

Comment: Here's the html `<a href="#" class="shop-item">
          <img src="img/haori-jacket.jpg" alt="Haori Jacket" class="shop-item__img" id="HaoriJacketimg">
          <div class="quickview">
            <span class="quickview__icon" id="Haori Jacket">Quick View</span>
            <span class="quickview__info">Haori jacket<br><span class="quickview__info--price" id="$210.00">$210.00</span></span>
          </div>
        </a>`

Comment: @Gilbert `$(this).attr('id');` gives you the item name because that's what I set the `id` to be. You will need to get the `innerHTML` from another `<span>`. I edited my answer to suit your needs.

Comment: Hey, can you please tell me why this isn't working: `<a href="#" class="shop-item">
          <img src="img/haori-jacket.jpg" alt="Haori Jacket" class="shop-item__img" id="HaorijacketImg">
          <div class="quickview">
            <span class="quickview__icon" id="Haori Jacket">Quick View</span>
            <span class="quickview__info">Haori jacket<br><span class="quickview__info--price" id="HaorijacketPrice">$210.00</span></span>
          </div>
        </a>`

Comment: The Javascript `var imgid = "#"+$(this).attr('id').replace(/\s/g,'') + "Img";
    var imgsrc = $(imgid).prop('src');
    var price = document.getElementById($(this).attr('id').replace(/\s/g,'') + "Price").innerHTML;
    $('#popupImg').prop('src', imgsrc);
    document.getElementById("clothingName").innerHTML = $(this).attr('id');
    document.getElementById("clothingPrice").innerHTML = price;` For some reason I can't now see the image and I also get an error in the console: "Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null" the weird thing is that it works on codepen (your example)

Comment: And the popup window `<div class="popup-item"><img src="" alt="Clothing item" class="wrapper-item__img" id="popupImg">
        <div class="product-info">
          <h2 class="heading-secondary" id="clothingName"></h2>
          <span class="product-info__price" id="clothingPrice"></span>
          <p class="product-info__text">Sed ornare tellus non lectus blandit faucibus. Curabitur convallis nibh ut libero lobortis ullamcorper. Aliquam ornare risus in orci iaculis egestas. Vivamus varius ipsum eu leo ...</p></div>`

Comment: @Gilbert For each piece of clothing you need a `span` with an `id` of the clothing name without spaces plus `"price"`. So for Haori jacket, the corresponding `id` of the price span would be `Haorijacketprice`. You are getting an error because no element with the `id` exists.

Comment: nvm, I fixed it, again the names of the ids had to match with each other. Thank you so much for helping me here, now one more question. If I want to add prev and next when the popup window is opened, would it be possible to keep this app functionality? I mean, if I click on the "next" button , will it show the descriptions of the matched item?

Comment: @Gilbert No problem. You will need to create another function for the next and previous buttons.

Comment: @Gilbert When I have time, I will try to implemenet that functionality in my demo.

Comment: thank you very much dude, you are the best! Good, just wanted to know If I could keep this code as it is to add the other function for the prev and next buttons. BTW, sorry to bother you with this after all your help but would you be so kind to explain this piece of code `"#"+$(this).attr('id').replace(/\s/g,'') + "Img";` I would like to know what I'm doing for future references. Again, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Gilbert `$(this).attr('id')` is getting the `id` attribute of the current event target. The `.replace(/\s/g,'')` is removing all the spaces. The `"#"` is used for the `jQuery` `id`selector and the `"Img"` is appending the unique part of the `id`.

Comment: @Gilbert And yes, you can keep the code as it is to implement the previous and next buttons' functionality.

Comment: The "#" is to target the ids for the images right? So if I wanted to target classes instead I would have to use "."+$ instead of the pound symbol (number symbol)

Comment: @Gilbert Exactly.

Comment: Hey @hev1, did you find some time to implement the functionality for the prev and next buttons? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Gilbert Sorry for the delay. I have implemented the functionality you wanted. Check it out.

Comment: don't worry man. Thanks a lot man, I really cant thank you enough for your all help. Btw, is it possible to make the prev button disappear if the first item is clicked and the opposite for the next button?

Comment: @Gilbert I made it so it would loop to through the images no matter what. Of course, what you want is entirely possible. I will make another demo for that soon.

Comment: Thanks a lot man!! is there any way that I can follow you on any social media?

Comment: @Gilbert I prefer not to reveal such information, nor do I spend a lot of time on social media.

Comment: Alright! When you have time and you do the other functionality, it'd be great if you could explain the logic behind the code for future references. And again, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Gilbert You're welcome and thanks for understanding.

Comment: @Gilbert I have implemented the functionality you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you're storing the price, image and description information in some database on your server or your computer. If you are, then the functionality is quite straightforward:

- When fetching all of the products from the server (e.g the Haori Jacket below), save the ID or whatever identifier you are using for each product and place it in the HTML markup using a `data-xxx` property. For example:

  ```
  <a href="#" class="shop-item"> 
    <img src="img/haori-jacket.jpg" alt="Haori Jacket" class="shop-item__img">
    <div class="quickview">
      <!-- random ID as example -->
      <span class="quickview__icon" data-id="560387">Quick View</span>
      <span class="quickview__info">Haori jacket<br><span class="quickview__info--price">$210.00</span></span>
    </div>
  </a>
  ```
- Inside your "on-click" function, fetch the item information using an AJAX call via jQuery (or something else) and then update that information in your `.popup-window` using jQuery.

  ```
  $('.quickview__icon').click(function (){
      // get the ID of the item
      let id = $(this).data('id');
      // Perform an AJAX call to get your information using the ID you
      // retrieved. I am assuming you've
      // obtained a JSON object with the properties 'title', 'src', 
      // 'description', and 'price'.
      let data = getDataFromServer(id);
      // Change popup shop item img source
      $('.popup-item .wrapper-item__img').attr('src', data.src);
      // Change title
      $('.popup-item .heading-secondary').text(data.title);
      // Change description
      $('.popup-item .product-info__text').text(data.description);
      // Change price
      $('.popup-item .product-info__price').text(data.price);
  });
  ```

jQuery is very useful to do those kinds of updates to the DOM, as you can very easily select the element you're looking to change via [CSS selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), as demonstrated above, and then use the numerous utility methods that jQuery provides to update the attributes or the content of said element.

**Note:** I used jQuery because you're already using it in your JavaScript snippet, so I assume you're using it in your project.

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking some time to answer my question, I really appreciate it. I'm not storing the information for each item anywhere since I didn't know how to do this. As you probably might've guessed, I'm a newbie at programming, this project is a big challenge to me. If you could only direct me to a tutorial of how to store the information or give me a quick example of how to do it that would be awesome. And again, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Gilbert we've all been there, don't worry :) It's great that you're challenging yourself. I think a quick example wouldn't suffice for that - however, I would highly recommend the [FreeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/) tutorials. They've got one for backend development, which would include storing the information in a database and retrieving it in your app.

Comment: Thanks. Oh I thought your approach was doable with only Jquery without the need of any back-end stuffs, did I get this wrong?

Comment: There's no need for getting data from the database if Gilbert can instead just get the `innerHTML` of the `span`s that hold the information he needs. However, this is still good for the paying part of the application.

Comment: @Gilbert no, my approach relies on dynamically getting the information you need from a database (backend). What hev1 says is true - you could simply get the information you need from the HTML if it is already there, like the item name. However, for more detailed information, like the description, you would likely retrieve it from a database.

Comment: Thank you guys. And yes, I'd like to rely only on JavaScript to build this app  .

Comment: @Gilbert For descriptions, you could put it in a hidden `input` tag or a `span` with `style="display: none;"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you could pass pass this to the function opening the pop-up, you could access the picture like `this.parentNode.parentNode.children[0];` the heading could be obtained by: `this.parentNode.children[1].innerHTML;`, and so on.

Note that the code gets more safe if you use getElementsByClassName instead of children. Sorry I can't make a more complete answer but I don't have time now, but this might help you forward.